# Can't see folder C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents in windows explorer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

When I open Windows explorer and navigate to

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\

I don't see the Documents folder listed

In folder options I have

1. Selected Show Hidden files and folders
2. Unchecked Hide protected operating system files

I am able to enter the full address in the address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on experimentation, it appears that Windows Explorer shows the "All Users\Documents" folder with the name "Shared Documents".  In other words, Windows Explorer just labels the folder differently, perhaps as a reminder that this folder acts differently.

If you go to a command window, change to the "All Users" directory, and do a DIR, you will see that in fact there is no "Shared Documents" directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Documents" folder for All Users, is there? Just "Shared Documents", which should be visible.

Comment: Try typing C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\ in the address bar. It should work

Comment: @Aducci, is that addressed to me? It "works" in that it shows the directories there, which do not include a "Documents".

Comment: Sorry I meant type in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\ in the address bar

Comment: It takes you to the "Shared Documents" folder. "Documents" is apparently automatically corrected to "Shared Documents" by Windows (or vice versa).

Answer (score -1):

What version of windows are you using (2000, XP, Vista, 7)?

"I am able to enter the full address in the address bar"

- what do you mean by this?  Are you able to type in the full address to the desired location in the address bar to view the files within? If so, you might have a corrupted profile... create a new profile in User Accounts, log into the new account, and try to see if you can view the folder.

You can also try a third-party winodws-manager (i.e. [xplorer2 lite](http://www.zabkat.com/x2lite.htm))

Comment: Windows XP. yes I am able to type the full address in the address bar to view the folder, but I cannot see it in the Windows Explorer GUI